# Forcing certain kinds of input with a form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, credit-card

I have a form to take credit card numbers. How can I force the following:

16 digits for a CC number, 15 if AmEx is selected from the select element

3 digits for a CSV number, 4 if AmEx is selected from the select element

2 digits for billingState (so it can only be NY, CA, NV, etc.)

5 digits for billingZip

(...) ... - .... format for phone numbers

Here's my code - http://slexy.org/view/s2dgDx7fV9

I'm using jQuery for much of the page. How can I do this in jQuery?

Thank you!

Comment: JavaScript. Are you using any of the JS libraries? MooTools, Prototype, jQuery..?

Comment: I've added js-code to my reply.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should add some javascript code. Usual HTMl does not provide such powerful mechanizm to control user input.

Using jQuery you could check Credit Card Number like this:

```
function isAmExSelected()
{
  return $("#creditCardType").val() == "American Express";
}

function containsOnlyDigits(str)
{
   return str.match(/[^0-9]/) == null;
} 

function validateCCNumber()
{
    var ccn = $("#creditCardNumber").val();
    var onlyDigits = containsOnlyDigits(ccn);
    if(isAmExSelected())
    {
       return ccn.length == 15 && onlyDigits;
    }
    else
    {
       return ccn.length == 16 && onlyDigits;
    }
}

function registerValidation(id, validateMethod, errorMethod)
{
    $(id).change(function(){
        if(validateMethod() == false)
        {
            errorMethod();
        }
    });
}

    $(document).ready(function(){
        registerValidation("#creditCardNumber", validateCCNumber, function(){alert("Error!")});
    });
```

You should write other validations by yourself.

Comment: I tried using the code you wrote, but there is no result. Even if I type in something that should not validate, I do not get an error alert. Here's all of my JS code: http://slexy.org/view/s26UsEHYHz

Comment: I've confused functions "load" and "ready". So the correct line is "$(document).ready". I've edited my sample. Then you should understand that my script does not consider many scenarios. For example, "changed" event fired only WHEN YOU LEAVE input. Or if you type 16-digits card number, then change Card Type to AmEx - nothing happened but should.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your inputs to keyup events. Also, you can validate a card by the first digit, i.e. 4 = Visa, 5 = Mastercard, 3 = Amex (usually), and 6 = Discover.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#creditCardNumber").change(function(){
        $value = $(this).val();
        $type = $value.substr(0,1);

        if ( $type == '3' ){
            $(this).attr("maxLength", 15);
        }
        else {
            $(this).attr("maxLength", 16);
        }

        if ( $(this).attr("maxLength") < $value.length ) {
        $len = ( $(this).attr("maxLength") - 1 );
            $(this).val($value.substr(0,$len));
        }
    });
});
```

You can do something similar with CVV, or even get the value of the card type instead of the first digit. For state and zip, assuming you're only accepting US based addresses, you could just set the maxLength attribute in your HTML. As for the phone number mask, there is a jQuery plugin that I've never used so I can't vouch for it, but hopefully this will set you off in the right direction.

http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/how-to-mask-input-with-jquery/

Comment: keyup event does not consider mouse copy-paste scenario.

Comment: Not that any event really handles that gracefully, nonetheless, how about this alternative? Also, they should just do away with asking for the card type, as they'll already know it as soon as that first digit is typed in.